# "A start job running for read and set NIS from /etc/sysconfig/network/" error in RHEL7 prevents boot-up

Tags: rhel7

I recently updated rhel7.4 to rhel7.5 and now it's stuck on boot up. How can I fix this booting up error?

> A start job running for read and set NIS domainname from /etc/sysconfig/network (10 hour/ No limit).

Note: I don't have NIS enable (I'm using winbind for auth).

Comment: You probably want _Super User_ for this, since it is not a programming question. If you can re-post it, that would be good. However, it is a bit brief - can you supply any further information about this error message? Have you put the error message into a search engine?

Comment: Hi,  Thank you for your response, but This is the only message i see in log in rescue mode and at boot where it hangs..... yes I can repost it. Do you want me to repost it under a different tag?

Comment: Under a different site please. I suggested SU, but [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) is probably better.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll do that